# What is the alternate to \n in python?

Tags: python, newline, end-of-line

I want to print the following output in python:

```
 99 buckets of bits on the bus.
 99 buckets of bits.
 Take one down, short it to ground.
 98 buckets of bits on the bus.
```

with a single print command and no "\n" characters in between. How can this be done?

Comment: If you want newlines, you kind of have to put them there... How could you expect the program to just guess that you want newlines?

Comment: Do you count `for i in range(10): print(i)` as a single print command or ten print commands? What about if you use a triple quoted string literal and there are newline characters but they're implicit?

Comment: I think the better question is why

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With triple-quoted string literals, you can use actual newlines instead of `\n`.

```
print(""" 99 buckets of bits on the bus.
 99 buckets of bits.
 Take one down, short it to ground.
 98 buckets of bits on the bus.""")
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import os
print os.linesep.join(["99 buckets of bits on the bus.",
 "99 buckets of bits.",
 "Take one down, short it to ground.",
 "98 buckets of bits on the bus."])
```

Comment: lol, nice edit!  Very impressive cross platform compatability

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
print chr(10).join([
    '99 buckets of bits on the bus.',
    '99 buckets of bits.',
    'Take one down, short it to ground.',
    '98 buckets of bits on the bus.'
])
```